# Difference between `is` and `==`?

Tags: python, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Python ‘==’ vs ‘is’ comparing strings, ‘is’ fails sometimes, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why)

In Python, what is the difference between these two statements:

`if x is "odp":`

`if x == "odp":`

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why

Comment: @SilentGhost I disagree.  The linked question contains the answer to this question, but to anyone stumbling around looking for a relatively simple answer to the question asked here, the linked question will not seem at all the same.

Comment: @David: and simple was already asked (quite recently too), you free to spend *your* time to find where it is, questions that have the same answers are duplicates in my book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` operator tests for equality

The `is` keyword tests for object identity; whether we are talking about the same object. Note that multiple variables may refer to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

The `is` operator compares the identity while the `==` operator compares the value. Essentially `x is y` is the same as `id(x) == id(y)`

Answer (score 1):

For implementation reasons, "odp" is a bad example, but you should not use is unless you want the possibility of two identical strings to evaluate to false:

```
>>> lorem1 = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
>>> lorem2 = " ".join(["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"])
>>> lorem1 == lorem2
True
>>> lorem1 is lorem2
False
```

As others have said, is tests identity, not equality.  In this case, I have two separate strings with the same contents.  **However**, you should not depend on this either:

```
>>> odp1 = "odp"
>>> odp2 = "".join(["o", "d", "p"])
>>> odp1 == odp2
True
>>> odp1 is odp2
True
```

In other words, you should **never** use is to compare strings.

P.S. 
In Python 2.7.10 `>>> odp1 is odp2` returns False.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#isnot)

> The operators *is* and *is not* test for object identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object. x is  not y yields the inverse truth value